# Редактор мобильных сайтов

Tags: jquery-mobile

Месяца два назад на сайте jQueryUI наткнулся на редактор мобильных сайтов, где можно было собрать страницу как конструктор.

Сейчас же, вместо той страницы - документация и ничего больше. Неужели конструктор убрали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде как убрали конструктор он лайн, но вот есть еще аналоги https://codiqa.com/demo